# Spring: Doing delete and create in same transaction so that rollback happens if any of them fail

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am trying to do delete and create of a pojo from inside the component. First I do the delete and then call save to create it again. The problem is that when the save fails, the delete isn't getting rollbacked.

```
@Transactional
public Item itemDeleteAndCreate(@NonNull Item itemToUpdate, Long itemId, @NonNull Item item) throws ParseException, IOException {
    item.setId(itemId);
//        validateSchema(item);
    mergeItemMandatoryAttr(item);
    validateAllMandatoryAttrPresent(item);
    validateStorageStrategy(item);
    Map<String, Object> exclusionTagsIfExist = exclusionRulesComponent.calculateExclusionTagsForProduct(item.getProductAttributes());
    Map<String, Object> itemAttribute = item.getProductAttributes();
    itemAttribute.put(EXCLUSION_TAGS, exclusionTagsIfExist);
    updateImageUrlWithImageData(item);
    log.info(String.format("Final item to be patched -> %s ", item.toString()));

    //ItemService itemService = new ItemService(itemBuilder);
    //return itemService.deleteAndCreate(itemToUpdate,item);
    itemBuilder.delete(itemToUpdate);
    Item updatedItem = itemBuilder.save(item);
    return updatedItem;
}
```

This is the controller from where the component is called.

```
public class ItemController extends AbstractController<Item, Long> {
private final ItemComponent itemComponent;
private final ItemBuilder builder;

@Override
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody @NonNull Item item,
                              @NonNull final HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.info("Received request to save " + item);

    try {
        Item savedItem = itemComponent.save(item, request);
```

From itemComponent.save, itemDeleteAndCreate is called like this

```
Item updatedItem = itemDeleteAndCreate(itemToUpdate, itemId, item);
```

I have enabled transaction in my config through EnableTransactionManagement.
I have also tried mode as AdviceMode.ASPECTJ but even that isn't helping.

Also I have tried writing wrapper class and putting this function in there and then creating an object of that class and calling this function on that object.

The Builder class eventually call Dao of crudRepository which also has a transactional annotation on its delete and save function.

This function is called from controller which doesn't have @transactional on it.

Also I have tried propagation level of acquires new but even that didn't work.

I have also tried rollbackfor Exception.class but even that doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How the save fails? What exception? Note that declarative transactions rollback only for runtime exceptions by default.

Comment: It fails because of constraint violation exception which is sub class of runtime exception and by the way thats the reason I also tried to do it for all exceptions through rollbackFor Exception.class but even that didn't work

Comment: Are you sure that `itemDeleteAndCreate` is part of a Spring bean? How do you create the instance that is called by your controller? A common mistake is to create the object with `new`.

Comment: I have update the detail you need. Everything is autowired through spring. I am not creating any object through new.

Comment: I have a very similar issue, did you end up fixing this?

Comment: Would recommend you to go through this https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html, especially 16.5.6 Using @Transactional, Might help you